# How do you set Kendo Switch width to be dynamic?

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use the Kendo Mobile Switch with custom labels that are more than just three characters, but the switch leaves the width the same, cutting off the text.  For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get it to be dynamic to the text width.  I've tried overriding .km-switch, nada. Notice the "Declarative Custom Label" switch.

Plunker demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5yjjY3uQE0QxPYzAuMB7?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.core.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/styles/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css" />

    <script data-require="jquery@1.9.1" data-semver="1.9.1" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.16" data-semver="1.2.16" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-kendo.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Switch Labels</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          Default Label:
          <input kendo-mobile-switch type="checkbox" />
          <br />

          Declaritive Custom Label:
          <input kendo-mobile-switch type="checkbox" k-on-label="'GOOD'" k-off-label="'BADDEREST'" />
          <br />

          k-options Custom Label:
          <input kendo-mobile-switch type="checkbox" k-options="options" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Switch Bindings</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          ng-model binding:
          <input kendo-mobile-switch type="checkbox" ng-model="myValue1" />
          value: {{myValue1}}
          <br />

          with on-change:
          <input kendo-mobile-switch type="checkbox" ng-model="myValue2" k-on-change="change(kendoEvent)"/>
          value: {{myValue2}}
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you have to adjust the width of the switch's wrapper and call the [refresh function](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/switch#methods-refresh) for the switch to recognize the new size so the toggle function moves the switch to the correct position.

You also have to adjust the position of the switch's background.

I updated your example and included a button that will do the trick. You maybe have to adjust the additional space I added:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCmpGgKi3W6LQiP3X1YW?p=preview

The function calculates the space that the "oversized" labels actual need and sets this space to the switch widget and calls the refresh function:

```
    $("input[data-role=switch]").each(function() {
        var kSwitch = $(this).getKendoMobileSwitch();
        if (!kSwitch) return;

        // calculate labels' width
        var tmpOn  = $("<span>").hide().css({"text-transform": "uppercase"}).html(kSwitch.options.onLabel);
        var tmpOff = $("<span>").hide().css({"text-transform": "uppercase"}).html(kSwitch.options.offLabel);
        tmpOn.insertAfter(kSwitch.wrapper);
        tmpOff.insertAfter(kSwitch.wrapper);
        var wOn     = tmpOn.width();
        var wOff    = tmpOff.width();
        var max     = Math.max(wOn, wOff) + 8;
        var width   = max + kSwitch.handle[0].offsetWidth + 2;
        tmpOn.remove();
        tmpOff.remove();

        kSwitch.wrapper.find(".km-switch-label-on").css({width: max + "px", left: "-" + max + "px"});
        kSwitch.wrapper.find(".km-switch-label-off").css({width: max + "px"});
        kSwitch.wrapper.css({width: width + "px"});
        kSwitch.wrapper.find(".km-switch-background").css({"background-position": width + "px 0"});

        kSwitch.refresh();
    });
```